# How to redirect the http request from web server to .Net Core Web API in application server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, networking, asp.net-web-api, architecture

We built a .Net Core Web API application(Having Controller, Business Layer, Service Layer, and DB access layer in it) with a repository and unit of work pattern and we deployed it in the application server since the application server alone can access the Oracle DB server.

The mobile app will consume this API to get/save data from oracle DB. Now the issue is our IT team is not ready to open up the port and they told us that all the requests to the application server should come through a web server.

**Case 1**:
If we deploy our Web API application on a web server mobile app can access API but It won't able to connect to Oracle DB as it can be accessed only through the application server.

**Case 2**:
If we deploy our Web API application on an application server it can connect to Oracle DB but the mobile app cannot consume Web API.

The approach I am thinking of is to create another Web API application and deploy it on the webserver and so that the mobile app will consume the newly created Web API on the webserver and then it redirects the request to an actual Web API in the application server

Is the above approach is right or What are the approaches or best practices** that we can take to resolve this issue? Please share your valuable thoughts on this

Comment: Can you call the application server from the web sever via http?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya Yes, they will allow webserver to communicate with application server over http

Comment: Anyways, Option 3, no code for you to write - just have your webserver forward requests through to the "application server" (which is/should be a webserver hosting your netcore app, it's controllers etc) as you're referring to it, using url rewrite proxying. The webserver can also deal with https and CORS meaning life for your app's web server (kestrel?) is very simple (but don't be tempted to do CORS stuff in both places otherwise life will get more confusing). Your IT team should know how to set up the url rewriting; it's a very typical operation

Comment: @Caius Jard Thanks for the response...Our netcore app can run on web server. But if we deploy it in the webserver net core app wont able to communicate to database as only application server was allowed to access db

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Your netcore app has controllers so to be of any use it has to run in a http server, like kestrel, IIS etc. When you launch it on your application server it starts a web server. What I'm calling a web server (a program that receives and responds to http requests) and and what you're calling a webserver (the hunk of metal your IT department installed and spun up with currently serves eg your corporate website) are different things; I'm using it in the software sense and you're using it in the hardware sense. My point is that you can have your IT department..

Comment: ..make "the webserver" (as they call it) forward requests through to your application (running in a http server software) on the "application server" (as they call it) using url rewrite. Just ask them to set up the URL rewrite rules and other stuff to make "the webserver" forward requests on to the internal http server hosting your netcore app on the "application server". The whole thing is a no-code for you

Comment: You need a two port application.  Port 1 is the WebServer that accepts client connections. Port 2 is a client that connects to the Application Server.  To solve the issue with credentials see the following msdn article on ROLES : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs